# Protractor 5.4.2 and Webdriver 12.1.6 along with the chromedrivers do not support chrome 76

Tags: protractor, selenium-chromedriver, gulp-protractor

Protractor 5.4.2 and latest Webdriver manager with Chromdriver versions donot work with new Chrome versions like 76.0.3809.100

I tried all of the suggestions Google and Protractor forums with no luck yet. I have tried the below -

**1. directConnect: true**

And then in my package.json added

> "postinstall": "cd ./node_modules/gulp-protractor && npm i
>   webdriver-manager@12.1.6 && cd ../../ &&
>   ./node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update --gecko=false"

I have tried this with and without adding explicit dependency

> "webdriver-manager": "12.1.6"

The below is the error message I see -

```
E/direct - Error code: 135
[12:06:06] E/direct - Error message: Could not find update-config.json. Run 'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.
[12:06:06] E/direct - Error: Could not find update-config.json. Run 'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.
```

2. **directConnect: false** and same dependencies and postInstall script as above. I am able to see the browser launch. But it does not interact with the browser.

   Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53' System info: host: 'MC02S8298G8WM', ip: '192.168.130.131', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.6', java.version: '1.8.0_181' Driver info: driver.version: unknown UnsupportedOperationError: touchSingleTap Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53' System info: host: 'MC02S8298G8WM', ip: '192.168.130.131', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.6', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
   **Driver info: driver.version: unknown**

My Chrome is currently on version 76.0.3809.100 and the latest chromedriver downloaded seems to be chromedriver_76.0.3809.12 for webdriver@12.1.6. I specifically tried mentioning a different higher version as well in webdriver update - 76.0.3809.68. The below was the error -

```
[12:24:58] E/launcher - Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'MC02S8298G8WM', ip: '192.168.130.131', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.6', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

I am pretty much flabbergasted and out of options. Is there anything else we could try?

P.S : Protractor upgrade is not feasible since we can't upgrade our node version.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue today and was able to resolve it with the following:

It seems you can force protractor to point to the updated version of chrome, and it works fine.

Figure out what version of chrome you are using (chrome://chrome in chrome address bar will work). Then [download the chrome driver that correlates to your version](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) and place it in and remove everything else from your selenium directory in your node_modules.

Then run the following

> ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome {end}

where {end} is the text that comes after `chromedriver_` in the name of the zip you downloaded (at the time of writing the file name is chromedriver_mac64.zip so {end} would be mac64.

After going through these steps I was able to run protractor with chrome again.